# Does tortoiseSVN support multiple iBugTraqProviders for same user/machine?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, fogbugz

The use case is that I use one development machine for different source trees.  Assuming I am using SVN/TortoiseSVN for all repositories I may have different issue trackers (e.g. Trac and FogBugz).

If I want to use the plugins for iBugTraqProvider - is that supported?  I would hop that you could set the plugin based on the path/folder.  However, I am not sure where to look for this to confirm.  I assume the source code, but I am a little lazy right now.

I am considering writing the plugin for FogBugz, but also need to use one for Trac.

Here is a page describing the interface.

http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-ibugtraqprovider.html#tsvn-ibugtraqprovider-1

This is especially important when I am on my boat doing programming ( boat-programming ) because there is not much room for multiple machines like I have at my home or office or home office.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the plugins are configured by path. You can install as many as you like. But of course, only one plugin can be used per working copy.

Comment: Awesome.  Not only do I get an answer, but I get THE answer from THE man!